# Map value from table to a different value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL:

table1:

```
+----------------+-------------------+
| meterName      | retailPrice       |
+----------------+-------------------+
| ND40rs v2 Spot |         8.5851642 |
| ND80rs v2 Spot |         4.5851642 |
+------------------------------------+
```

table2:

```
+----------------+-------------------+
| mapMeterName   | time              |
+----------------+-------------------+
| nd40_spot      |               1.2 |
| nd80_spot      |               2.5 |
+------------------------------------+
```

I want to map the value of meterName to the mapMeterName, and get the multiplication of the time and the retailPrice. so meterName ND40rs v2 Spot is equivalent to nd40_spot and I want the 1.2 x 8.5851642 value, and similary nd80_spot and ND80rs v2 spot are equivalent and I want 2.5 x 4.5851642

To get something like:

```
+----------------+-------------------+----------------------------+
| meterName      | retailPrice       | (time x retailPrice)= cost |
+----------------+-------------------+----------------------------+
| ND40rs v2 Spot |         8.5851642 |              10.302197     |     
| ND80rs v2 Spot |         4.5851642 |              11.4629105    |
+------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Is there a one liner in MySQL i can use to do this type of mapping?

Comment: This sounds like a basic *inner join*, please share your current attempt and explain what issue you have; do you have defined foreign keys?

Comment: Hi @abinitio; I understand that you are not able to do simple inner join as the key values in both tables are different.
Just wanted to check are there more records in these tables;
If 'Yes' are all other records in same format ?
I hope; 'meterName` and 'mapMeterName` are distinct keys in both the tables

Comment: Hi @Avidan - yes, an inner join won't work. There are more records, these are just some example tables - there are several different meterNames and mapMeterNames along with dates and various other columns, but the basic problem is the same. I though a select case would be the way to go, but it doesnt seem to work. materName and mapMeterName are distnct.

Comment: Does your `meterName` always matches the pattern `XXXX ???? YYYY` (where ???? means any substring) and according `mapMeterName` matches `XXXX_YYYY`? If so then try `.. FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.meterName, ' ', 1), '_', SUBSTRING_INDEX(table1.meterName, ' ', -1)) = table2.mapMeterName ..`

Answer (score 0):

You would need another table to store the mapping.

```
table3
+----------------+-------------------+
| meterName      | mapMeterName      |
+----------------+-------------------+
| ND40rs v2 Spot |         nd40_spot |
| ND80rs v2 Spot |         nd80_spot |
+------------------------------------+
```

Then use a join:

```
SELECT table1.meterName, table1.retailPrice,
  table1.retailPrice * table2.time as `(time x retailPrice)= cost`
FROM table1
JOIN table3 USING (meterName)
JOIN table2 USING (mapMeterName);
```